# Symfony FOS User Bundle Login Check Action

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Override login_check action. I need to add some extra functionality. When user submit form i need to check his role and some additional fields in user entity.

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SecurityListener
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $router;
    private $session;

    public function __construct($userManager, $securityContext, $session, $router)
    {

        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $this->securityContext->getToken()->setAuthenticated(false);
        $this->securityContext->setToken(NULL);

        return new RedirectResponse('http://stackoverflow.com');
    }
```

I'm use events. I created custom event listener. And override onSecurityInteractiveLogin (class LastLoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface).

1. Redirect doesnt work.
2. How can i logout user ? Is my approach correct?
3. 2 events fired: 1) my 2) default, why?
4. When i remove token second default event redirect me on login form, but last login date write in database.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: 1 : may be $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('...')); ?